# How to programmatically move a control defined with the Windows Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I think this is an odd one. I have a screen (Windows Forms) created using the Forms Designer. I now want to programmatically change the width of one of the controls, ie at runtime, according to some or other criterion.

My problem is that I can't seem to do this. My approach is to assign a new value to the Width property somewhere after the form class InitializeComponent() method has been executed (say at the end of the form constructor). A watch shows me the control property has been changed, but the subsequently displayed screen ignores the new value and uses the value assigned in InitializeComponent().

Am I trying to do something impossible? Is there some voodoo in the background that blocks this for a control created by the Designer, or am I just going about it the wrong way?

Comment: You will need to post the code that you have tried to A. provide an example of what you want to do. B. So we can see where you are going wrong...

Comment: Please add your code, where you change the width now

Comment: How do I do that? It's quite large so I can't add as a comment

Comment: Here's the stripped down Form constructor:
<code>
  public ScreenEditor()
  {
   //
   // Required for Windows Form Designer support
   //
   InitializeComponent();
   this.InitializeDesignHost();
   ....
            this.panel2.Width = 1000;
            this.panel2.Invalidate();
  }
</code>

panel1 occupies the width of the form, achored bottom, left
panel2 is contained within panel1 and occupies the entire height of panel1 and the left half, and is anchored top and left.

The task is to the move the right edge of panel2 at runtime so that it occupies more or less of the width of panel1.

Comment: Apologies for the badly formatted code - I'm struggling with this editor a bit.

Comment: Have you tried handling an event for when the Form is loaded and in view? Something like: this.Loaded += MyLoadedEventHandler;
In the method MyLoadEventHandler adjust the width.

Comment: I'll try that and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Yup that does the trick. Thanks - if you repeat your comment as an 'answer' I'll mark it as 'accepted'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried handling an event for when the Form is loaded and in view? Something like: this.Loaded += MyLoadedEventHandler; In the method MyLoadEventHandler adjust the width. – Davio 2 hours ago

That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check [`Control.AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize.aspx) and [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties.
specially:

> ***`Control.Anchor`*** : Gets or sets the edges of the container to which a control is bound and determines how a control is resized with its parent.

Comment: The control in question is a panel anchored top and left, and I want to move the right edge. Autosize is false.

Answer (score 0):

If the control is a `Label` ensure that the `Autosize` property is set to false, otherwise .NET will resize the control to fit content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Invalidate` method?

Comment: No. Invalidate the control in question?

Comment: Yes. It forces control to redraw.

Comment: Tried that - no improvement. The control in question is a panel anchored top and left, and I want to move the right edge.